# In Groovy Eclipse, is it possible to get intellisense for methods added through an AST transformation?

Tags: eclipse, groovy, intellisense, abstract-syntax-tree

In Groovy Eclipse, is it possible to get intellisense for methods added through an AST transformation?

So if I add a method `foo` to the class `Demo` with an AST transformation, typing `new Demo().` would have `foo` in the list of suggested methods that pops up.

Comment: I suspect, in short, the answer is no. Consider when AST transformations are run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no, not yet.  This is a feature that we are actively working on and we will likely be releasing some sort of DSL descriptor language that end-users can use to extend content assist and type inferencing in the editor.

Comment: are you aware of the support already present in IntelliJ? It would be nice if you could work together on the same DSL instead of creating two different ones. Some frameworks like GPars already have the DSL bundeled. See http://jetbrains.dzone.com/articles/custom-groovy-dsl-support and http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/GRVY/Scripting+IDE+for+DSL+awareness

Comment: Here's the DSL bundled with GPars: http://git.codehaus.org/gitweb.cgi?p=gpars.git;a=blob;f=src/main/groovy/groovyx/gpars/Definitions.gdsl;h=377160fc8e08f5f036af4bc5ba5b08356b169075;hb=HEAD

Comment: Yes, we are aware of this and we are determining how to proceed.  The IntelliJ language is nice, but it does expose some internal IntelliJ-specific objects in the syntax.  For example, the enclosingCall() method that is used in the GPars file that you link to returns an object of type PSIElement.  So, we have to think a bit harder how the existing gdsl can be adapted towards an Eclipse environment.

Comment: Has any  progress been made on this?